Не создаётся БД автоматически в Spring Boot
Не могу понять, где может быть ошибка.
Order.java:
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "customer")
    private String customer;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private short price;

    @Column(name = "readiness")
    private boolean readiness;

    public Order() {

    }

    public Order(String customer, String description, short price, boolean readiness) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.readiness = readiness;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public short getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(short price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isReady() {
        return readiness;
    }

    public void setReadiness(boolean isReady) {
        this.readiness = isReady;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", customer=" + customer + ", desc=" + description + ", readiness=" + readiness + "]";
    }
}

OrderController.java:
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Order;
import com.example.demo.repository.OrderRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders(@RequestParam(required = false) String customer) {
        try {
            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

            if (customer == null)
                orderRepository.findAll().forEach(orders::add);
            else
                orderRepository.findByCustomerContaining(customer).forEach(orders::add);

            if (orders.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(orders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/orders/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrderById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Optional<Order> orderData = orderRepository.findById(id);

        if (orderData.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(orderData.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
        try {
            Order _order = orderRepository
                    .save(new Order(order.getCustomer(), order.getDescription(), order.getPrice(), false));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_order, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> updateOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Order order) {
        Optional<Order> orderData = orderRepository.findById(id);

        if (orderData.isPresent()) {
            Order _order = orderData.get();
            _order.setCustomer(order.getCustomer());
            _order.setDescription(order.getDescription());
            _order.setReadiness(order.isReady());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(orderRepository.save(_order), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/orders/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        try {
            orderRepository.deleteById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteAllOrders() {
        try {
            orderRepository.deleteAll();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/orders/readiness")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> findByPublished() {
        try {
            List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findByrReadiness(true);

            if (orders.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(orders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

OrderRepository.java:
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.Order;

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{

    List<Order> findByrReadiness(boolean readiness);

    List<Order> findByCustomerContaining(String customer);
}


application.properties:
spring.application.name=demo

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dry_cleaning
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= 1234
server.port=8081

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <url/>
   <licenses>
       <license/>
   </licenses>
   <developers>
       <developer/>
   </developers>
   <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
   </scm>
   <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
           <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>


Во первых, Hibernate не создаёт базы данных, а только подключается к текущей, которая указана в datasource.url.
Хотя, в Hibernate можно контролировать создание схемы в базе данных.
Потому, что в конфигурации
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

то, схема не создаётся, а создаются только таблицы, если они отсутствуют в схеме.
Для того, чтобы создавалась схема нужно указывать свойство hibernate.ddl-auto как create или create-drop.

Теперь работает. Спасибо!
